# как загрузить в бд oracle данные из файла через скрипт ruby

Tags: linux, bash, ruby, scripts

Есть файл log.txt с данными `4 ./WORK6/AXE/CNA5/LBN/2212 20-12-2022 20-12-2022-17:53:16` - 4 значения. Есть бд в oracle db.test куда нужно загрузить эти значения. Я нашел как подключиться к бд:

```
    #!/usr/bin/ruby
require'active_support/core_ext'
require 'oci8'
require 'ruby-plsql'
require 'csv1'
#ARGV.size > 0 || abort("Usage: #{__FILE__} <any>")
#========================================================================
#                      
PARAMETERS
#========================================================================
#$es_delta = 5 
# change if need start for old period
dir_to = '/home/iumadma/test/script/NumOfLines.rb'
#========================================================================
def v_cdr_params(date_now)
plsql.connection = OCI8.new('esb', 'esb432', '//10.29.11.5:1521/esb')
#
plsql.connection = OCI8.new('ium', 'ium3_115', '//10.29.11.5:1521/ium3')
```

как теперь передать данные в бд из файла? нужно что то вроде

```
#puts "sql started..."   
v_cdr_params = plsql.select('insert into db.test (NUMBER_OF_LINES,SOURCE,DATA,DATE_OF_STATISTIC) select col1, col2 col 3 from log.txt ')
```

Нужно определять массив и через него грузить? Но как тогда в него из файла данные загрузить. Либо можно напрямую из файла?
И можно ли сюда встроить запрос на bash чтобы из него данные передавать в бд а не через файл?
Как проще всего сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Сначала прочитай данные из файла. Потом преобразуй эти данные в формат, который можно вставить в базу данных. И с помощью SQL вставь данные в БД.

```
require 'oci8'
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach("log.txt", col_sep: ' ') do |row|
  number_of_lines, source, data, date_of_statistic = row

  connection.exec("INSERT INTO db.test (NUMBER_OF_LINES, SOURCE, DATA, DATE_OF_STATISTIC) VALUES (:1, :2, :3, TO_TIMESTAMP(:4, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))", number_of_lines, source, data, date_of_statistic)
end
```